# In PHP, how to use one PDO connection for different sections of the same page?

Tags: php, pdo

I have been practising oop in PHP for a while, and now I came to this problem.

How can I make one connection for different section of the same html page, where there are different PHP tags? For example below is my connection class.

```
   // class
        class connection{
           public function dbconnection(){
            $user = "user";
            $pass = "pass";
            $pdo_connection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=shefilco_madimo
            ', $user, $pass);
              return $pdo_connection;               
              }
       }


   <div id="section_1">
    <?php
     include("connection.php");
         class section_one{  
         public function __construct(){
          $this->conn = new connection();
          $this->conn = $this->conn->dbconnection();
    }
     public function fetchdata1(){
          //my codes to fetch data
        }
       $object1=new  post_photos();
       $object1->display_post_photos();
    ?>
    </div>
   <div id="section_2">
      <?php
     include("connection.php");
         class section_one{  
         public function __construct(){
          $this->conn = new connection();
          $this->conn = $this->conn->dbconnection();
    }
     public function fetchdata2(){
          //my codes to fetch data
        }
       $object2=new  post_photos();
       $object2->display_post_photos();
    ?>
   </div>
   <div id="section_3">
       <?php
     include("connection.php");
         class section_one{  
         public function __construct(){
          $this->conn = new connection();
          $this->conn = $this->conn->dbconnection();
    }
     public function fetchdata3(){
          //my codes to fetch data
        }
       $object3=new  post_photos();
       $object3->display_post_photos();
    ?>
    </div>

      //my page that has different sections
     And the  connection class :
```

Comment: Instantiate the connection outside of the classes, and pass it into them via the constructor.

Comment: Your idea on PHP scripts is wrong. All the sections are withing the same PHP script, and therefore you need to include connection only once.